# Fermi-Pasta-Ulam for the beam equation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, structural-beam

The [Fermi-Pasta-Ulam numerical experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Pasta%E2%80%93Ulam_problem) is based upon the discrete wave equation, with a small non-linearity added to the forcing term.  Does anybody know of similar research performed on the beam equation?  That is, the potential energy is defined using second differences instead of first differences, or eqivalently
$$ \ddot x_n = -(x_{n+2}-4x_{n+1}+6x_n-4x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}) + \text{non-linearity} .$$
This equation is dispersive, that is, the speed of waves is wavelength dependent.  I am wondering if this will lead to thermalization.